# Using selenium to find out if someone responded to a text

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

My company uses an PC app called Podium to text customer's phones.
I want to use selenium to make a list of people that did and did not respond to me.

In my limited knowledge the only way I can think of to do this is to search for the elements on the page by class that display the users name within the text box and then iterate through them all.
This way if it finds a user name element in the text box that is not mine then I know they responded.

```
    #loop through all elements with CLASS_NAME 'chakra-avatar__initials'

    name = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'chakra-avatar__initials').text

    if name != my_name:
       print(responded)
```

My issue is I have no idea how to do this in selenium.
It returns the first value it finds when it finds the class element it is looking for.
How do I iterate through all elements of a single class on the page?

Much appreciated.

Comment: Hit F12 and compare the incoming messages with the outgoing ones. There'll likely be some classname etc. unique to sender vs the receiver

Comment: Yeah there is a class that contains the names of the sender and receiver but it is the same class.
So I need to iterate over all elements of the same class, which I'm not sure how to do.

Comment: I'm suggesting that you possibly (likely?) don't need to know the names of the sender or receiver unless you specifically want the name.

For example if the return message element looks like 

`<div class="xyz" name="response1"></div>`

Comment: Yeah, sadly everything is labeled the same whether it's sender or receiver :(

Comment: Can you share the html you're seeing (you can anonymize the data obviously)?

Comment: I'm sorry how do I anonymize the data?

Comment: I just meant that if the data is sensitive data for whatever reason, you can replace the specific data with placeholder text
ex. `<span>Harry Private-lastname</span>` would become `<span>John Smith</span>`

Comment: try use driver.find_elements instead of driver.find_element